# iMX6Q SABRE-AI Android M6 LVDS Backlight going off while bootup

Tags: android, imx6

I am working with i.MX 6Quad SABRE-AI board and I tried to flash android image and boot from SD card.
I have followed "android_M6.0.1_2.1.0_docs/Android_Quick_Start_Guide" section 4.3.

**I have successfully flashed and booted from SD card , while booting i can see splash screen from u-boot and kernel logo (tux) on the LVDS screen , but suddenly the backlight of LVDS goes off (once the kernel starts).**

**Also, We have found out that enable pin to LVDS is HIGH during the bootup (backlight ON) and it becomes LOW (backlight OFF) once the kernel starts.**

***Note :*** We can see the contents on the LVDS screen (if we look from an angle ) , so we believe if backlight is enabled LVDS would work proper for us.

**Suspicious parts in bootup logs:**

```
pwm-backlight supply power not found, using dummy regulator
MIPI DSI driver module loaded
MIPI DSI driver module loaded
mxc_sdc_fb fb@0: registered mxc display driver ldb
imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: IPU DMFC DP HIGH RESOLUTION: 1(0,1), 5B(2~5), 5F(6,7)
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
```

**How to make logic high on **BACKLITE_ON** pin of **"Port Expander A"** from android M6 kernel?**

Comment: I am afraid that you are not configuring the LVDS and backlight enable pin in kernel. So check their configuration in your kernel device tree.

Answer (score 0):

You might configure the GPIO of the backlight control properly in boot loader .

Possibility is that either

(1) the GPIO is being used by other driver in kernel space which is overwrite your boot loader configuration, check the GPIOs which is used in kernel driver by using GPIO sysfs command on terminal

Or

(2) If the backlight pins controlled from backlight driver, check logic state of on and off handled in driver